# How to pass a concatenated string to HTML using Jekyll include?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, liquid

I have to make a string of values separated by semicolons and pass this string to a script in HTML include to then parse and output the result.

My jekyll markdown page:

```
---
layout: page
title: Our team
permalink: /team
---

{% assign cfhandles=""%}

{% for person in site.data.team-handles %}
    {{ cfhandles | append: person.handle }}
    {{ cfhandles | append: ";" }}
{% endfor %}

{% include load-ratings.html cfhandles=cfhandles %}
```

My load-ratings.html:

```
<script>
    let url = "https://codeforces.com/api/user.info?handles=";
    let handles = "{{ include.cfhandles }}";
    console.log(handles);
    url = url + handles;
    console.log(url);
    async function load() {
        let obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();
        console.log(obj);
        for (let cur_user of obj["result"]) {
            let cur_handle = cur_user["handle"];
            let user_rating = cur_user["rating"];
            document.getElementById(cur_handle.toLowerCase()).innerHTML = "Рейтинг: " + user_rating;
        }
    }
    load();
</script>
```

My team-handles.yml:

```
- handle: bob1
  name: Bob

- handle: alice2
  name: Alice
```

When I open the developer console, it shows me that in JS the `handles` variable is empty (but it shouldn't be like that). How do I pass the needed string to the file so it shows correctly?

I already tried using {%- -%} Liquid tags, but it didn't change the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% assign cfhandles=""%}

{% for person in site.data.team-handles %}
    {% assign cfhandles = cfhandles | append: person.handle | append: ";" %}
{% endfor %}

{% include load-ratings.html cfhandles=cfhandles %}
```

The code basically assigns the new strings `bob1;` and `alice2;` to the existing variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped. I didn't assign the concatenated string so it remained unchanged the whole time.

Comment: Yeah, found it out using `{{ cfhandles | inspect }}` :)